# How display array of objects in table using angularjs dynamically?

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table

I am using angular.js for my font-end, node.js for server side and PostgreSQL for database.

Now, I am having some list of values in DB.

Database:

[image]

Controller code:

I got below output in *`console`*.

```
console.log($scope.items);

$scope.items = [
  {
    salary_head_name : 'BASIC',
    salary_head_value : 15000,
    salary_head_type : 'E'

  }, {    
    salary_head_name : 'HRA',
    salary_head_value : 7500,
    salary_head_type : 'E'    
  },{    
    salary_head_name : 'Conveyance',
    salary_head_value : 1600,
    salary_head_type : 'E'    
  },{    
    salary_head_name : 'Med. Allow',
    salary_head_value : 1800,
    salary_head_type : 'E'    
  },{    
    salary_head_name : 'PF',
    salary_head_value : 1800,
    salary_head_type : 'D'    
  }
];
```

Note: For readability I printed only few records in the above `array` (edited manually), actually it prints all the records.

Expected output in UI:

[image]

And also I want to print the sum of `Earnings` and `Deductions` in the *Total* fields in the above table.

Comment: Take a look at [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive to make your table with angularjs. You should post some code of what you tried to get this to work, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: node.js tag is not required here, your question is related to angular.js only

Answer (score 1):

Use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), For basic Idea look at following code:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate']).controller('repeatController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{

                salary_head_name : 'BASIC',
                        salary_head_value : 15000,
                            salary_head_type : 'E'

            }, {

                salary_head_name : 'HRA',
                         salary_head_value : 7500,
                            salary_head_type : 'E'

            },{

                salary_head_name : 'Conveyance',
                         salary_head_value : 1600,
                            salary_head_type : 'E'

            },{

                salary_head_name : 'Med. Allow',
                        salary_head_value : 1800,
                            salary_head_type : 'E'

            },{

                salary_head_name : 'PF',
                         salary_head_value : 1800,
                            salary_head_type : 'D'

            }];
});
})(window.angular);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngRepeat-production</title>
  <link href="animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="ngRepeat">
  <div ng-controller="repeatController">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Earnings</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.salary_head_name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.salary_head_value}}</td>
        <td>{{item.salary_head_type}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```